# Combine the conditions to filter ancestor and property by GQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am create a Endpoint to query my Datastore by GQL, and I want to specify the ancestor and property, but GQL seems cannot combine those 2 conditions. Am I missed anythings?

My GQL is:
`select * from Product where __key__ HAS ANCESTOR Key(modle1, '0') AND timestamp > 0`

And I used the library: com.google.cloud.datastore
Is there have any other way to do my goal?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What do you see?

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I fixed it. I need to upload a index definition for my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I figured out my problem.
I MUST to upload a index definition for my query.

So, I follow this guide - [Cloud Datastore Indexes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/indexes), try to upload my index.
I am succeed in the end, but it took me a whole night.

**If you use Google Cloud SDK to develop your appengine, there is a small hint for upload index.**
Many Q&A or documents said you should upload indexs with appcfg.cmd/appcfg.py/appcfg.sh, but if you are developing appengine with Google Cloud SDK instead of Google Appengine SDK, you should not use that command. Replace with

```
gcloud app deploy indexes.yaml
or
gcloud datastore create-indexes
```

Ref: [Migrating from AppCfg to gcloud Command Line](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrating-from-appcfg-to-gcloud)

No matter what you develop your appengine with, you should write indexes.yaml (If you develop with Java, you will found some documents ask you to write datastore-indexes.xml, drop it, gcloud is seems not support that.).